# I can change the value of the inner text but I can't save the edited node back to HTML document

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

```
string xpath = "//div[ @id='attendance_no']";
 var doc = web.Load(@"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\projese302\newtmp.html");
            HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
            node.InnerHtml = node.InnerHtml.Replace(node.InnerText (string)dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells["Sayı"].Value);
```

I am trying to change and save the value of the inner HTML by getting user input, for instance when user enters a number - the value of the inner HTML has to be edited 2. I can change the value of the inner text but I can't save the edited node back to HTML document, how can I do this, please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "HtmlAgilityPack"?

You can get the node and change its Text. Then call `Save Method` to save the change.

```
var path = @"test.html";
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

HtmlTextNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='Div1']//text()") as HtmlTextNode;
node.Text = "new text";
// save the change
doc.Save(@"test.html");
```